# DynamoDB Marshal and unmarshal golang time.Time as millis since epoch

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-go

The sdk by default marshals `time.Time` values as RFC3339 strings. How can you choose to marshal and unmarshal in other ways e.g. millis since epoch?

The SDK mentions the Marshaler and Unmarshaler interfaces but does not explain how to use them.

Comment: There is no way to "choose". What you have to do is declare a custom type that implements the Marshaler/Unmarshaler interfaces.

Answer (score 8):

(As I was about to post my question I figured out the answer by looking into how `UnixTime` worked).

To use a custom Marshaler and Unmarshaler you can create a custom type.

```golang
type MillisTime time.Time

func (e MillisTime) MarshalDynamoDBAttributeValue(av *dynamodb.AttributeValue) error {
    millis := timeAsMillis(time.Time(e))
    millisStr := fmt.Sprintf("%d", millis)
    av.N = &millisStr
    return nil
}

func (e *MillisTime) UnmarshalDynamoDBAttributeValue(av *dynamodb.AttributeValue) error {
    millis, err := strconv.ParseInt(*av.N, 10, 0)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    *e = MillisTime(millisAsTime(millis))
    return nil
}

func timeAsMillis(t time.Time) int64 {
    nanosSinceEpoch := t.UnixNano()
    return (nanosSinceEpoch / 1_000_000_000) + (nanosSinceEpoch % 1_000_000_000)
}

func millisAsTime(millis int64) time.Time {
    seconds := millis / 1_000
    nanos := (millis % 1_000) * 1_000_000
    return time.Unix(seconds, nanos)
}
```

NOTE: Example above uses the new number literal syntax introduced in go 1.13.

You can easily marshal and unmarshal structs using `MarshalMap` and `UnmarshalMap` but the downside is that the fields in your struct type have to use MillisTime instead of `time.Time`. Conversion is not easy but is possible.

The SDK defines a `UnixTime` type which will handle marshaling and unmarshaling between `time.Time` <=> seconds since epoch.

Comment: For those using old Go (before 1.13), it will be enough to remove underscores (`_`) and everything will work as expected. But it's much better to update Go to the latest version.

Comment: Great answer, just what I needed

Answer (score 0):

Dynamodb SDK is formating by default in RFC3339 nano, which looks like this:

2023-05-20T20:03:08.206801611Z

```
time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339Nano)
```

https://pkg.go.dev/time